# Delete registry key value HKLM/Software without admin privilege

Tags: winapi

Is there any way in Windows 7 for standard user to delete registry key value from HKLM/ Software/Wow64_32node? This key also has virtual key.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way in Windows 7 for standard user to delete a registry key value from HKLM\ Software\Wow6432Node?

The simple answer is no. Standard user does not have rights to modify keys under HKLM.

That said, registry keys are securable objects and so it is possible to apply ACLs to registry keys. It is conceivable that the registry key you are wishing to delete has had ACLs applied to make it possible for lower privilege users to modify it. However, that is very unusual, and unless somebody has performed such actions, then the default security prevails. Namely that standard user cannot modify keys under HKLM.